# Unexpected values returned when using facebook open graph and a like button

Tags: facebook, meta, facebook-opengraph

I have the following HTML in my HTML head:

```
<meta content="***" property="fb:admins">
<meta content="***" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="Site.com" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="http://site.com/thumbnail.png" property="og:image">
<meta content="activity" property="og:type">
<meta content="Test Title" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://site.com/page/?Id=56&amp;Source=" property="og:url">
<meta content="Test Activity Description" property="og:description">
```

But rather than the details I have specified showing up in my facebook feed, instead I get a link to site.com/page (without the URL variables after it), the title seems to be coming from the `<title>` rather than the `<meta content="Test Title" property="og:title">` and the description is coming from the first `<p>` on `site.com/page` (which isn't there when you include the URL variables)

any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Running the page through linter has thrown up some interesting issues.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwaggleb.com%2F12454874521145474-2%2F

The problem seems to stem from the fact that the image, the URL, the title and description are generated using javascript. When facebook calls back does it not allow the JS to run before fetching the results?

I need to change the data with javascript unless there is a way to pass the whole page through PHP, pick out the data I need and then place the correct URL, title, description and image into the meta tags. I **do not** have direct access to the database, so I must retrieve this data from the `DOM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it was cached by facebook before you put in these tags.
Try to clean them in Linter: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: thanks for alerting me to linter, I have edited my question with what I have found.

Comment: No, you have to put correct tags for facebook without DOM manipulation. But you can detect with php if it is the facebook bot, and 'echo' the right tags for him: http://pastebin.com/Deb4HZS7